# Optimize input instead of network in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I am trying to optimize the inputs in some required task and I don't want to update my network as its freezed. I have written a minimal example but its not working as z has the same value in all iterations.  I am sure that I am doing some silly mistake in this process. Any guidance is highly appreciated.
thanks.

```
import torch

z = torch.rand((1,6))
z.requires_grad_(True)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([z], lr= 0.1)

criteria = torch.nn.MSELoss()


for i in range(5):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    print(z)
    loss = criteria(z, z+torch.rand(1))
    #print(loss)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

##output
tensor([[0.1105, 0.8152, 0.2820, 0.1122, 0.6645, 0.7211]], requires_grad=True)
tensor([[0.1105, 0.8152, 0.2820, 0.1122, 0.6645, 0.7211]], requires_grad=True)
tensor([[0.1105, 0.8152, 0.2820, 0.1122, 0.6645, 0.7211]], requires_grad=True)
tensor([[0.1105, 0.8152, 0.2820, 0.1122, 0.6645, 0.7211]], requires_grad=True)
tensor([[0.1105, 0.8152, 0.2820, 0.1122, 0.6645, 0.7211]], requires_grad=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradients are always 0. This can be seen as follows:

```
import torch

z = torch.rand((1,6))
z.requires_grad_(True)
z.retain_grad()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([z], lr= 0.1)

criteria = torch.nn.MSELoss()


for i in range(5):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    # print(z)
    loss = criteria(z, z+torch.rand(1))
    # print(loss)
    loss.backward()
    print(z.grad)
    optimizer.step()
```

```
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
tensor([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
...
```

I don't have the mathematical proof, but it probably comes from the definition of the target `z+torch.rand(1)`, that directly depends on the input `z` by a simple addition.

Answer (score 0):

Everything seems okay, except your criterion which makes no sense. No amount of optimization can decrease the difference between `z` and `z+rand()`, because the difference between these values is `rand()` which is completely independant of `z`. I'm not sure what you wanted to achieve or imitate with this example.

Try something like `loss = criteria(z, torch.zeros_like(z))` and you'll see `z` converge toward 0 in very few iterations.

Comment: Even if the targets are random, the tensor values should not be constant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, issue was with my target values in this question. But actually one of my block in the graph was breaking up the calculation of gradients due to `torch.no_grad` wrapper, Here are the details about the task for future users as it was something like that.

```
import torch

z = torch.rand((1,6))
z.requires_grad_(True)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD([z], lr= 0.1, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=1e-4)

criteria = torch.nn.MSELoss()
l = torch.nn.Linear(6, 6)#.cuda()
p = torch.nn.Linear(6, 6)#.cuda()

#optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(parameters, lr=0.5)


for i in range(5):
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    print(z)
    
    fun = l(z)
    
    out = p(fun)
    loss1 = criteria(z,fun)
    print(loss1)
    
    loss2 = criteria(out,fun)
    #print(loss)
    loss = loss1 + loss2
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    print(z.grad)
```